# Incorrect plotting of points in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

```
31.238993  ,  121.490515
30.19777778  , 71.47416667
25.617214  ,  85.1446954
5.316667  ,  -4.033333
```

I wished to simplify plot the above points on map.

Code Used:

```
map = Basemap()
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color='coral')
x, y = map(lat_list[:5], long_list[:5])
map.scatter(x, y, marker='D',color='m')
plt.show()
```

It gives me this output:
[image]

This seems incorrect. The points are placed wrong. It should something like -http://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/?id=560996

I am probably making a mistake in specifying incorrect parameters, but can't understand where. From what I have read from the documentation, map() should map the co-ordinates to the map system used. Please help me in identifying the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on coordinates and example, maybe you need to change order in map.

```
x, y = map(long_list[:5], lat_list[:5])
```

Because in geography latitude is Y-coordinate and longitude is X-coordinate.